# Parse Error: syntax error: unexpected '{'

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error

I have this code that processes a user then redirects them to the user homepage.

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    $file = file_get_contents("userdb.html");
    if(!strpos($file, $username)) {
        echo "Your username was not found in our database. Please go back and try again.";
    } else {
        echo "Redirecting...";
        if (md5($password) == !strpos($file, (md5($password))) {
             echo "Redirecting..."
             header ('Location: ./userhome.php')
        } else {
             print "Whoops! Your password seems to be incorrect. Go back and try again."
        }
    }
?>
```

And I get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in userprocess.php on line 11
```

Could someone tell me the problem please? I think it may be the if inside of if statement, but what can I do for an alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Try to use good IDE and you'll see syntax errors marked. NetBeans or PhpStorm.

Comment: Are you going to come back soon and ask, why redirection didn't work?

Comment: Are you really saving usernames and passwords in an html file? Even if you hash and salt, you should still not hand them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this line is missing a closing bracket:

```
if (md5($password) == !strpos($file, (md5($password))) {
```

Count the number of `(` and `)` -- they need to match.

When you fix this, you'll still get errors, because PHP statements need to end with semi-colons.

All of the following lines are missing their semi-colon:

```
echo "Redirecting..."
header ('Location: ./userhome.php')
print "Whoops! Your password seems to be incorrect. Go back and try again."
```

You need to fix them all before you'll be able to run the program without syntax errors.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Right after I posted this I realized the semicolons (a seriously stupid problem for me) but thank you for the fix of the if statement. It was a well thought out an clear answer. Thank you.

Comment: Also, an `echo` followed by `header` and `print` is just too obvious an error to ignore...

Comment: @Linus - indeed, but I was already straying outside the bounds of the original question by pointing out the semicolons. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (md5($password) == !strpos($file, (md5($password)))
```

to

```
if (md5($password) == !strpos($file, md5($password)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a right parenthesis in the line:

```
if (md5($password) == !strpos($file, (md5($password))) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    $file = file_get_contents("userdb.html");
    if(!strpos($file, $username)) {
        echo "Your username was not found in our database. Please go back and try again.";
    } else {
        echo "Redirecting...";
        if (md5($password) == !strpos($file, md5($password))) {
             echo "Redirecting...";
             header ('Location: ./userhome.php');
        } else {
             print "Whoops! Your password seems to be incorrect. Go back and try again.";
        }
    }
?>
```