# PHP, session error

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with my **check.php** for a login system I am building,
the error reads

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/ob219/public_html/logsystem/check.php on line 3
```

My code is

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']) || $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] !== true {
header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

I have tried to remove the brackets {} but then it has a problem with header

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse Error: syntax error: unexpected '{'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7059753)

Comment: You just forgot an `)` at the end of `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing your closing parenthesis:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']) || $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] !== true {
```

should be

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']) || $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] !== true) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']) || $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] !== true)
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
?>
```